# Oracle 11g: Extract data from XML using xmltable, xmlagg and pivot

Tags: oracle11g, pivot, xquery, clob, xmltable

I have the following XML:

```
<record>
    <leader>02220cim a2200325 a 4500</leader>    
    <datafield tag="035" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">P286</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="100" ind1="1" ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">Gold, Claudia M.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="300" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">1 disque son. (6h47) :</subfield>
      <subfield code="b">numérique ;</subfield>
      <subfield code="c">12 cm.</subfield>
    </datafield>  
    <datafield tag="650" ind1=" " ind2="6">
      <subfield code="a">Émotions chez l&apos;enfant</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="650" ind1=" " ind2="6">
      <subfield code="a">Parents et enfants</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="655" ind1=" " ind2="4">
      <subfield code="a">Enregistrement numérique sur CD.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="700" ind1="1" ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">Taussig, Sylvie</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="700" ind1="1" ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">Marcelli, Daniel</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="852" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">GBQ</subfield>
      <subfield code="b">QO</subfield>
      <subfield code="c">DC13378</subfield>
      <subfield code="d">32002518936826</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield tag="852" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
      <subfield code="a">GBQ</subfield>
      <subfield code="b">QO</subfield>
      <subfield code="c">DC13378</subfield>
      <subfield code="d">32002518936859</subfield>
    </datafield>    
  </record>
```

I need to convert the values in rows into columns. For example:

```
leader    datafield_035   datafield_100   datafield_300  datafield_650 ...
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
02220...
```

Here is what I did:

1/ Step1:

```
insert into table_data(leader, tag, subfield) 
(
select x.leader,x1.tag, x2.subfield
from table_xml t
  cross join XMLTABLE (xmlnamespaces (default 'http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim')  
        , '/collection/record'  
          passing t.xml_document
          columns leader VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'leader',                                        
          datafield      xmltype       path './datafield'  
        ) x
    cross join XMLTABLE (xmlnamespaces (default 'http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim')  
        , '/datafield[@tag=245 or @tag=100 or @tag=300 or @tag=260 or @tag=650 
                or @tag=520 or @tag=091 or @tag=534 or @tag=245 or @tag=500 or @tag=655 or @tag=505]'     
         passing x.datafield
          columns tag VARCHAR2(20) PATH '@tag',           
         subfield xmltype PATH './subfield'
          )x1
      cross join XMLTABLE (xmlnamespaces (default 'http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim')  
        , '/subfield'     
         passing x1.subfield                
         COLUMNS subfield varchar2(2000) PATH '.'
          )x2      
where t.id=3
)
;
```

2/Step 2:

```
INSERT INTO table_CLOB (leader, tag, subfield)
select leader, tag, 
rtrim(xmlagg(XMLELEMENT(e,subfield, ' ; ').extract('//text()')order by subfield).getClobVal(),' ; ') as subfields
from table_data
group by leader, tag
;
```

3/ Step3:

```
insert into table_result(leader, tag, subfield)
(    select leader, "'091'" as cote, "'100'" as auteur, "'245'" as titre,
        "'300'" as Desc_Mater, "'260'" as edition,"'520'" as resume, "'534'" as version,
        "'500'" as notes, "'650'" as sujet
      from
      (
        select leader, tag, dbms_lob.substr(subfield,2000,1) as col
        from table_clob
      ) 
      pivot(max(col) for tag in ('091', '100', '245', '260','650','520','300','534','500'))
    );
```

After these steps, I get the result that I expect but the performance is not really good.

Is there anyway I can do one shot and get the final result?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [subquery factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF30048) (also known as common table expressions, or CTEs) instead of permanent (or even temporary) tables.

But you don't really need to do all that work, you can use use [`listagg()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm) and your first query:

```
select x.leader
  , listagg(case when x1.tag = '091' then x2.subfield end, ' ; ')
      within group (order by x2.subfield) as cote
  , listagg(case when x1.tag = '100' then x2.subfield end, ' ; ')
      within group (order by x2.subfield) as auteur
  , listagg(case when x1.tag = '245' then x2.subfield end, ' ; ')
      within group (order by x2.subfield) as titre
  , listagg(case when x1.tag = '300' then x2.subfield end, ' ; ')
      within group (order by x2.subfield) as desc_mater
  , listagg(case when x1.tag = '260' then x2.subfield end, ' ; ')
      within group (order by x2.subfield) as edition
  , listagg(case when x1.tag = '520' then x2.subfield end, ' ; ')
      within group (order by x2.subfield) as resume
  , listagg(case when x1.tag = '534' then x2.subfield end, ' ; ')
      within group (order by x2.subfield) as version
  , listagg(case when x1.tag = '500' then x2.subfield end, ' ; ')
      within group (order by x2.subfield) as notes
  , listagg(case when x1.tag = '650' then x2.subfield end, ' ; ')
      within group (order by x2.subfield) as subjet
from table_xml t
  cross join XMLTABLE ( ... ) x
    cross join XMLTABLE ( ... )x1
      cross join XMLTABLE ( ... )x2      
where t.id=3
group by x.leader;
```

Which gets the same result form your sample, apart from the apostrophe losing it's entity encoding; which may be a good thing.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f18b/2); I was going to put the CTE version on there for reference but it's killing it - it often isn't happy with XML or CTEs, and it's intermittently struggling with the `listagg` version too; so here's the full version of both:

```
with table_data as (
select x.leader,x1.tag, x2.subfield
from table_xml t
  cross join XMLTABLE (xmlnamespaces (default 'http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim')  
        , '/collection/record'  
          passing t.xml_document
          columns leader VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'leader',                                        
          datafield      xmltype       path './datafield'  
        ) x
    cross join XMLTABLE (xmlnamespaces (default 'http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim')  
        , '/datafield[@tag=245 or @tag=100 or @tag=300 or @tag=260 or @tag=650 
                or @tag=520 or @tag=091 or @tag=534 or @tag=245 or @tag=500 or @tag=655 or @tag=505]'     
         passing x.datafield
          columns tag VARCHAR2(20) PATH '@tag',           
         subfield xmltype PATH './subfield'
          )x1
      cross join XMLTABLE (xmlnamespaces (default 'http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim')  
        , '/subfield'     
         passing x1.subfield                
         COLUMNS subfield varchar2(2000) PATH '.'
          )x2      
where t.id=3
),
table_clob as (
select leader, tag, 
rtrim(xmlagg(XMLELEMENT(e,subfield, ' ; ').extract('//text()')order by subfield).getClobVal(),' ; ') as subfield
from table_data
group by leader, tag
),
table_result as (
select leader, "'091'" as cote, "'100'" as auteur, "'245'" as titre,
        "'300'" as Desc_Mater, "'260'" as edition,"'520'" as resume, "'534'" as version,
        "'500'" as notes, "'650'" as sujet
      from
      (
        select leader, tag, dbms_lob.substr(subfield,2000,1) as col
        from table_clob
      ) 
      pivot(max(col) for tag in ('091', '100', '245', '260','650','520','300','534','500'))
)
select * from table_result;

select x.leader
  , listagg(case when x1.tag = '091' then x2.subfield end, ' ; ')
      within group (order by x2.subfield) as cote
  , listagg(case when x1.tag = '100' then x2.subfield end, ' ; ')
      within group (order by x2.subfield) as auteur
  , listagg(case when x1.tag = '245' then x2.subfield end, ' ; ')
      within group (order by x2.subfield) as titre
  , listagg(case when x1.tag = '300' then x2.subfield end, ' ; ')
      within group (order by x2.subfield) as desc_mater
  , listagg(case when x1.tag = '260' then x2.subfield end, ' ; ')
      within group (order by x2.subfield) as edition
  , listagg(case when x1.tag = '520' then x2.subfield end, ' ; ')
      within group (order by x2.subfield) as resume
  , listagg(case when x1.tag = '534' then x2.subfield end, ' ; ')
      within group (order by x2.subfield) as version
  , listagg(case when x1.tag = '500' then x2.subfield end, ' ; ')
      within group (order by x2.subfield) as notes
  , listagg(case when x1.tag = '650' then x2.subfield end, ' ; ')
      within group (order by x2.subfield) as subjet
from table_xml t
  cross join XMLTABLE (xmlnamespaces (default 'http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim')  
        , '/collection/record'  
          passing t.xml_document
          columns leader VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'leader',                                        
          datafield      xmltype       path './datafield'  
        ) x
    cross join XMLTABLE (xmlnamespaces (default 'http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim')  
        , '/datafield[@tag=245 or @tag=100 or @tag=300 or @tag=260 or @tag=650 
                or @tag=520 or @tag=091 or @tag=534 or @tag=245 or @tag=500 or @tag=655 or @tag=505]'     
         passing x.datafield
          columns tag VARCHAR2(20) PATH '@tag',           
         subfield xmltype PATH './subfield'
          )x1
      cross join XMLTABLE (xmlnamespaces (default 'http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim')  
        , '/subfield'     
         passing x1.subfield                
         COLUMNS subfield varchar2(2000) PATH '.'
          )x2      
where t.id=3
group by x.leader;
```

Comment: Hi @Alex: thanks but I dont know why I am getting errors : "SQL error 17410 No more data to read from socket" ?

Comment: @giluy - with both approaches? That usually means the DB session crashed - might have something in the server alert log. I ran this in 11.2.0.4; perhaps your version is hitting a bug. Which would be awkward. (Maybe that's what's killing SQL Fiddle, which is on 11.2.0.2). What version gets that error?

Comment: HI @Alex: Mine is Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition 11.2.0.4.0 
It gives me that error when I put "Create table test_result as (...) ; ".
But, in general, both approaches consume a lot of time. I can say it is over 10mins because the XML file is huge, and I use xmlagg instead of listadd (because some fileds are over 4000 characters).

Comment: @giluy - yes, I get that with CTAS too. From the ORA-07445 log looks like a known bug; see MOS document 1943615.1. There may be a workaround, but unless CTAS is vital, creating it first and then doing an insert seems to work OK. If `listagg()` is ruled out because you have values that are too long, the CTE version may still be a little faster than your original since you aren't doing the intermediate inserts; or you could create your own CLOB aggregator. But the size of your document may be dwarfing any savings anyway; I'd test the approaches with a subset to see how much difference they make.

Comment: Thanks for your advices.